# How serious are npm module vulnerabilities?

Tags: malware, node.js, npm

Obviously any known vulnerabilities are not great, but I'm curious how much I should be concerned about them.

I've seen plenty of articles that talk about the rise in malware/spam in npm packages:

- [NPM malware attack goes unnoticed for a year](https://www.techtarget.com/searchsecurity/news/252525968/NPM-malware-attack-goes-unnoticed-for-a-year)
- [Malicious NPM packages are part of a malware “barrage” hitting repositories](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2021/12/malicious-packages-sneaked-into-npm-repository-stole-discord-tokens/)
- [Worried about occasional npm malware scares? It's more common than you may think](https://www.theregister.com/2022/02/03/npm_malware_report/)

But nonetheless it seems like so many projects where you run npm install you get greeted with a slew of medium to critical vulnerabilities reported by npm audit. What gives?

These articles make me feel like running npm/gulp on my device is a horrible idea, but yet it seems that man projects just don't address the vulnerabilities in their dependencies to avoid breakage.

Answer (score 0):

> How serious are npm module vulnerabilities?

This is basically like asking how serious a generic "illness" is. It very much depends on the kind of vulnerability, if it is exploitable in the specific environment and what impact it has if it is exploitable. So you need to look much deeper than just checking how many vulnerabilities there are.

> NPM malware attack goes unnoticed for a year ...

The links you cite are not about the usual vulnerabilities at all. They are about malware distributed using the npm ecosystem, either by adding modules which sound similar to others (typo squatting) or by compromising existing modules.

Vulnerabilities are accidents introduced by lack of competence, quality control, time or too much complexity. Malware instead are deliberate attacks and therefore needs to be handled differently. So if you find out that you have malware introduced by npm it is much more serious than having a common vulnerability.